# Rule mediator integration with wso2 ei 6.2.0

Tags: wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-esb

I want to create a rest api where i send the json request payload and it should change the json key value based on rule defined using rule mediator

i have already tried the Sample 600 and modified with below code to achieve my requirement.

```
<rule xmlns:brs="http://wso2.org/carbon/rules">
                <source xpath="//val"/>
                <target action="replace" resultXpath="//val" xpath="//val"/>
                <ruleSet>
                    <properties/>
                    <rule resourceType="regular" sourceType="inline"><![CDATA[
                        rule Invokeval
                        when
                        val: String()
                        eval(val.equals("someval"))
                        then                        update(drools.getWorkingMemory().getFactHandle(val),"WORKINGDROOL");
                        end                        
                    ]]></rule>
                </ruleSet>
                <input namespace="http://services.samples" wrapperElementName="jsonObject">
                    <fact elementName="val" namespace="http://services.samples" type="java.lang.String" xpath="//val"/>
                </input>
                <output namespace="http://services.samples" wrapperElementName="jsonObject">
                    <fact elementName="val" namespace="http://services.samples" type="java.lang.String"/>
                </output>
            </rule>
```

getting RuleMediator invalde source value Error

Comment: Did you manage to solve this problem? I'm facing it now.